# Get all post and count from db phalcon

Tags: php, database, count, blogs, phalcon

**[use case]**

I have 2 users in my blog.

User 1 has 3 posts and has the following amount of views:

- post 1: 20 views
- post 2: 40 views
- post 3: 100 views

User 2 has 2 posts and has the following amount of views:

- post 1: 15 views
- post 2: 40 views

**[question]**

I want to count the total amount of views (of all the posts) for each user in [phalcon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalcon_%28framework%29). I can't figure it out. I am unable to bind or make this query.

**[controller]**

```
public function index()
{   
  $pcount = Blogs::findBybauthor($this->session->get('uname'));
  $posted = count($pcount);
  $x = [];
  $v = Blogs::findBybauthor($this->session->get('uname'));
  foreach($v as $a)
  {
   echo($a->views.'<br/>');
  }    
}
```

Comment: Instead of `find` you can do `count`: `Blogs::countBybauthor($this->session->get('uname'));`. This will return the number of `author` occurrences in `blogs`

Comment: Actually i want to count how many people reached in each users post. thats why first i want to count how many post have in each user and then how many people reached each post for that user's posts and then addition its.

Comment: So you want the total amount of views / user or just total amount of views of all posts?

Comment: Yeah! Absolutely right! Timothy. I want the total amount of views / user of all posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently not able to verify this example. [But from looking at the docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#generating-calculations), this should point you in the right direction.

Instead of using `find` we are using `sum`.

This will return an array with the total amount of views, grouped by author.

```
$viewsPerAuthor = Blogs::sum(
    array(
        "column" => "views",
        "group"  => "bauthor"
    )
);
```

This will return the total amount of views for a specific author

```
$total = Blogs::sum(
    array(
        "column"     => "views",
        "conditions" => "bauthor = :author:",
        "bind"       => array('author' => $this->session->get('uname'))
    )
);
```